# spring jdbctemplate: different behaviour on different app servers (date issue)

Tags: spring, jdbctemplate

I am running the same select query on the same database using the same code but using 2 different app servers.

Query: Find a certian day's entries in a journal.

1) Existing legacy app server (BroadVision running on unix):
    Select title, content from journal where entry_date = TO_DATE(?, 'DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS');

DEBUG:core.StatementCreatorUtils:Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 1, parameter value [Thu Sep 29 14:32:58 IST 2011], value class [java.util.Date], SQL type unknown

This works fine

2) JBoss app server (Running on windows):
    Select title, content from journal where entry_date = TO_DATE(?, 'DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS');

DEBUG:core.StatementCreatorUtils:Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 1, parameter value [Thu Sep 29 14:41:26 IST 2011], value class [java.util.Date], SQL type unknown

ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

Any ideas how to get this running on the JBoss app?

Thanks,

Kenny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code seems incorrect to me. The `TO_DATE` function's goal is to transform a string in a given format into a date. And you're not passing a string as argument to this function, but a `java.util.Date` object.

You should remove the use of the `TO_DATE` function, transform your `java.util.Date` into a `java.sql.Timestamp` object, and use `setTimestamp` to pass the argument to your prepared statement.

The fact that it worked as is on your unix box looks like an accident to me.